# Can I get the text, or other attributes of a widget, once I find it?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a unit or integration test for Flutter. Can I get the text, or other attributes of a widget, once I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`WidgetTester`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester-class.html) provides multiple methods for probing into the UI tree (widgets, states, elements, render objects). Here's an example of how you can use it to read out the text out of a `Text` widget:

```
tester.widget(find.byType(Text)).data;
```

See also https://flutter.io/testing/#widget-testing, which explains how to write widget tests in Flutter.

Comment: is very outdated. anyone know what's the latest update? how to access state, properties inside a Text